# Windows Phone 7 Mango Update - SkyDrive functionality available for developers?

Tags: windows-phone-7, onedrive

I read a lot about new SkyDrive syncing features (syncing of documents, pictures...) coming with Mango. But will this functionality be available to developers or is it limited to  applications by Microsoft?

I think this would be great but I didn't find any information on it.

Comment: My guess is no due to privacy and security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current release of the SDK, SkyDrive functionality is **not available** to third-party developers. As a matter of fact, there is no official public SkyDrive API. There is the unofficial [SkyDrive .NET API Client](http://skydriveapiclient.codeplex.com/), but since it is not supported by Microsoft, it will be a bit risky to use it in an app that is outside the "just for fun" zone.

Answer (score 0):

More recently there has been an official API released but it is nothing but Javascript libraries. You have to create a browser instance and manipulate that.

Also it's limited to fiddling with photos and documents. If you want to use SkyDrive as a cloud filesystem the a better option is http://cerulean.codeplex.com/documentation