# Upload a file to Skydrive

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, onedrive

Is there an official API in the upcoming Mango release of WP7 to upload a file to skydrive?

If it is, where can I find an example and the API description?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Microsoft SkyDrive have an API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307696/does-microsoft-skydrive-have-an-api)

Comment: apparently there is some API, but not for uploading: http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_live/b/windowslive/archive/2011/07/20/developers-learn-how-to-bring-data-from-hotmail-messenger-and-skydrive-to-your-mobile-apps.aspx

Comment: I have uploaded a complete example of a real-world application on my blog - MetroSky - It demonstrates nearly all SkyDrive features you can use through Live SDK 5.0 and Windows Phone 7 Mango:
[Complete Sample](http://blog.mecum.biz/2012/01/a-complete-windows-phone-7-mango-skydrive-sample-metrosky/)

Comment: @user1064198 - we would prefer if you didn't spam posts with the same boilerplate answer promoting content on your blog. If you're doing that then the questions are probably duplicates so flag as such. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473472/windows-phone-7-mango-update-skydrive-functionality-available-for-developers):

> SkyDrive functionality is not available to third-party developers. As
>   a matter of fact, there is no official public SkyDrive API.

Also see this other [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307696/does-microsoft-skydrive-have-an-api).

**UPDATE:** (Credit to Eric for pointing out the change in API accessibility)

From the [window steam blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_live/b/windowslive/archive/2011/12/07/skydrive-apis-for-docs-and-photos-now-ready-to-cloud-enable-apps-on-windows-8-windows-phone-and-more.aspx):

> The new version of the Live Connect APIs and the Live SDK for Windows
>   Phone has now shipped. Please read on to learn more about what’s
>   available now, or visit the [Live Connect developer center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live//default.aspx) to get
>   even more details.

The [developer center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live//default.aspx) notes that:

> The Live SDK is also available for Windows Phone, Android and iOS. The
>   Live Connect APIs use open standards like OAuth 2.0, JSON, and XMPP,
>   making them easy and familiar to work with.

Comment: This is no longer true. SkyDrive launched their APIs in December 2011: http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_live/b/windowslive/archive/2011/12/07/skydrive-apis-for-docs-and-photos-now-ready-to-cloud-enable-apps-on-windows-8-windows-phone-and-more.aspx

Comment: @EricWarnke, thanks for pointing this out - I've updated my answer to reflect the public API status.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [Live SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/ff621310) to integrate SkyDrive into your Windows Phone applications. Please see [our code samples on GitHub](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK/tree/master/Samples/WindowsPhone/LiveSDKSample).

Answer (score 5):

Windows Phone applications can use [the Live SDK for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live/ff621310) to create, read, write or delete photos and documents in SkyDrive.

Comment: I manage to build and run this application. There is sing in button. When I click it shows a progress bar and get back to same the page. I does nothing. Could you please suggest me how can I use ur application to upload something to skydrive. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure you set your application to "Mobile" in the live website.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there is no official API for uploading a file to SkyDrive from Mango/WP7... see for example http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_live/b/windowslive/archive/2011/06/07/don-t-wait-for-your-cloud-use-hotmail-and-skydrive-today-on-your-pc-mac-or-phone.aspx

You could use an unofficial client - see http://skydriveapiclient.codeplex.com/

EDIT:

Since SkyDrive is accessible via WebDAV you can use for the basic tasks like uploading a file any WebDAV-capable client...

Answer (score 2):

A preview on the Live SKD has been announced at Build11.

You can signup and get the API inclusive documentation at:
http://connect.microsoft.com/site1226

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft SkyDrive "API" is implemented as JavaScript libraries. Not only do they NOT support basic general filesystem management operations, you have to instantiate a browser object and pull its chain, which is extremely kludgy.

I have directly implemented some classes that will allow you to use SkyDrive as a cloud based file system. I have not supported any of the social media aspects.

My classes will allow you to

- authenticate
- create and delete folders
- create, read, write and delete files

Available here: http://cerulean.codeplex.com/documentation

Answer (score 0):

no need for a library

oneDrive install client locally

used System.IO.File.Copy ("path to local file", "path to my local onedrive directory")

Comment: sorry, but you misunderstood my question